# Adding python modules to AzureML workspace

Tags: python, azure, scikit-learn, python-module, azure-machine-learning-service

I've been working recently on deploying a machine learning model as a web service. I used Azure Machine Learning Studio for creating my own Workspace ID and Authorization Token. Then, I trained LogisticRegressionCV model from **sklearn.linear_model** locally on my machine (using python 2.7.13) and with the usage of below code snippet I wanted to publish my model as web service:

```
from azureml import services

@services.publish('workspaceID','authorization_token')
@services.types(var_1= float, var_2= float)
@services.returns(int)

def predicting(var_1, var_2):
    input = np.array([var_1, var_2].reshape(1,-1)
return model.predict_proba(input)[0][1]
```

where *input* variable is a list with data to be scored and *model* variable contains trained classifier. Then after defining above function I want to make a prediction on sample input vector:

```
predicting.service(1.21, 1.34)
```

However following error occurs:

```
RuntimeError: Error 0085: The following error occurred during script 
evaluation, please view the output log for more information:
```

And the most important message in log is:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LogisticRegressionCV'
```

The error is strange to me because when I was using normal *sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression* everything was fine. I was able to make predictions sending POST requests to created endpoint, so I guess **sklearn** worked correctly. 
After changing to *LogisticRegressionCV* it does not.

Therefore I wanted to update sklearn on my workspace.

Do you have any ideas how to do it? Or even more general question: how to install any python module on azure machine learning studio in a way to use predict functions of any model I develpoed locally?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For installing python module on Azure ML Studio, there is a section [`Technical Notes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/cdb56f95-7f4c-404d-bde7-5bb972e6f232/#Anchor_3) of the offical document `Execute Python Script` which introduces it.

The general steps as below.

1. Create a Python project via `virtualenv` and active it.
2. Install all packages you want via `pip` on the virtual Python environment, and then
3. Package all files and directorys under the path `Lib\site-packages` of your project as a zip file.
4. Upload the zip package into your Azure ML WorkSpace as a dataSet.
5. Follow the offical [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/execute-python-scripts#importing-existing-python-script-modules) to import Python Module for your `Execute Python Script`.

For more details, you can refer to the other similar SO thread [Updating pandas to version 0.19 in Azure ML Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46222606/updating-pandas-to-version-0-19-in-azure-ml-studio/46232963#46232963), it even introduced how to update the version of Python packages installed by Azure.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is this solution works with Linux as well? What is the equivalent of "Lib\site-packages" what is supposed to uploaded as zip?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who came across this question like I did in hopes of installing modules in AzureML notebooks; it seems the current environments sit on Conda on the compute so it's now as simple as executing

`!conda env list`

```
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /anaconda
azureml_py36             /anaconda/envs/azureml_py36
```

`!conda -n azureml_py36 -y <packages>`

from within the notebook environment or doing pretty much the same without the `!` in the terminal environment

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with the same issue: error 0085

I was able to resolve it by using Azure ML code example available from their library: 
Deployment of AzureML Web Services from Python Notebooks

can be found at https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Notebook/Deployment-of-AzureML-Web-Services-from-Python-Notebooks-4

I won't copy the whole code here, but I used it exactly as is and it worked with Boston dataset.  Then I used it with my dataset, and I no longer got error 0085.  I haven't tracked down the error yet but it's most likely due to some misbehaving character or indent.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this code actually works, but the original problem is that a_kord wanted to use another model (LogisticRegressionCV) instead of the one in this tutorial (LogisticRegression). I also confronted the fact that only some Sklearn model types work in ML Studio.