# Updating pandas in Azure ML Studio results in an Error

Tags: python, pandas, azure, anaconda, azure-machine-learning-service

This question is based on the solution of an other question the user user4446237 asked: [Updating pandas to version 0.19 in Azure ML Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46222606/updating-pandas-to-version-0-19-in-azure-ml-studio)

I have followed the steps provided in the answer and I also get the information at the end, that I have imported the new version of pandas (0.23.3) instead of pandas (0.18.0). However after retrieving the version of the packages the code runs into an error:

```
Caught exception while executing function: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\server\invokepy.py", line 192, in batch
    idfs = [parameter for infile in infiles
  File "C:\server\invokepy.py", line 194, in <listcomp>
    infile, is_buffer=False)]
  File "C:\server\XDRReader\xdrutils.py", line 47, in XDRToPyObjects
    return XDRBridge.xdr_to_py_positional(attrList)
  File "C:\server\XDRReader\xdrbridge.py", line 216, in xdr_to_py_positional
    retList.append(XDRBridge.xdrobject_to_dataframe(key, value))
  File "C:\server\XDRReader\xdrbridge.py", line 155, in xdrobject_to_dataframe
    }, index=np.arange(len(columns[0].values())), copy=False)
  File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 223, in __init__
    mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 356, in _init_dict
    columns = data_names = Index(keys)
  File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 129, in __new__
    from .range import RangeIndex
SystemError: Parent module 'pandas.indexes' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

The code I am using is pretty much the same from Jay Gong:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
print(pd.__version__)
del sys.modules['pandas']
del sys.modules['numpy']
del sys.modules['pytz']
del sys.modules['six']
del sys.modules['dateutil']
sys.path.insert(0, '.\\Script Bundle')
for td in [m for m in sys.modules if m.startswith('pandas.') or m.startswith('numpy.') or m.startswith('pytz.') or m.startswith('dateutil.') or m.startswith('six.')]:
    del sys.modules[td]
import pandas as pd
print(pd.__version__)
# The entry point function can contain up to two input arguments:
#   Param<dataframe1>: a pandas.DataFrame
#   Param<dataframe2>: a pandas.DataFrame
def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):
```

Is there anything I can do about this problem or am I reaching the limitations of Azure ML Studio's Python Script Module.

Comment: I have contacted the Microsoft Support about this problem. This is a hacky way to get an updated version of a python package running. It is not supported. The Microsoft Support suggested to use the Azure Machine Learning Workbench. This answer was also provided in the question I have shared above.